# DAX formula to get the latest date based on multiple criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this DAX formula for a Measure in PBI,  I need to return the latest date if it matches the form name AND if it is Finalized i.e. equals 1  (the Finalized field is either 1 or 0).

I have the formula as below, however, it's not returning the result I want.  It's still returning the date even when [Finalized] is zero.   Where I got it wrong?

```
Observed_Date = 
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'Form Results'[DateObserved] ),
        'Form Results'[Formname] = "Office Worker" 
            && max('Form Results'[Finalized])=1
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove max for `'Form Results'[Finalized])` in your dax formula

```
Observed_Date = CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'Form Results'[DateObserved] ), 'Form Results'[Formname] = "Office Worker" && 'Form Results'[Finalized])=1
```

Comment: thanks, it worked.  don't know what I was thinking putting a max there :(